# ISAPI Rewrite rule changing https request to http one, for specific page

Tags: isapi-rewrite

What should look isapi rewrite rule which can change **https** to **http** for a specific page, ex:

https://www.portal.com/mypage to http://www.portal.com/mypage

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} (.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/mypage)
RewriteRule .? https://%1%2 [R,L]
```